# Entity Framework Core 2 - Pesquisa recursiva em relacionamentos muitos-para-muitos

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core

Fiz um relacionamento muitos-para-muitos usando EF Core 2, método Code First. Segundo visto [nesse link](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-1-the-basics/), é necessário criar uma entidade de join:

```
public class ClienteModel
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string NomeEmpresa { get; set; }
    public string NomeContato { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ConteudoConversa { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataHoraConversa { get; set; }
    public List<ClienteServicoModel> ClienteServico { get; set; }
}

public class ServicoModel
{
    public int ServicoId { get; set; }
    public string NomeServico { get; set; }
    public List<ClienteServicoModel> ClienteServico { get; set; }
}

public class ClienteServicoModel
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public ClienteModel Cliente { get; set; }
    public int ServicoId { get; set; }
    public ServicoModel Servico { get; set; }
}
```

Definição das relações no context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ClienteModel>().HasKey(m => m.ClienteId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ServicoModel>().HasKey(m => m.ServicoId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ClienteServicoModel>().HasKey(m => new { m.ClienteId, m.ServicoId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<ClienteServicoModel>().HasOne(m => m.Cliente).WithMany(e => e.ClienteServico).HasForeignKey(m => m.ClienteId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ClienteServicoModel>().HasOne(m => m.Servico).WithMany(e => e.ClienteServico).HasForeignKey(m => m.ServicoId);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Entidade criada, faço a inclusão:

```
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<ClienteModel>> Post(ClienteModel Cliente)
{
    var clienteServico1 = new ClienteServicoModel();
    var clienteServico2 = new ClienteServicoModel();
    var cliente = new ClienteModel()
    {
        NomeEmpresa = "Teste",
        NomeContato = "Teste",
        Telefone = "Teste",
        Email = "Teste",
        ConteudoConversa = "Teste",
        DataHoraConversa = DateTime.Now
    };

    var servico1 = new ServicoModel()
    {
        NomeServico = "Teste 1"
    };

    var servico2 = new ServicoModel()
    {
        NomeServico = "Teste 2"
    };

    clienteServico1.Cliente = cliente;
    clienteServico1.Servico = servico1;

    clienteServico2.Cliente = cliente;
    clienteServico2.Servico = servico2;

    cliente.ClienteServico = new List<ClienteServicoModel>();
    cliente.ClienteServico.Add(clienteServico1);
    cliente.ClienteServico.Add(clienteServico2);

    _context.Clientes.Add(cliente);
    _context.Servicos.Add(servico1);
    _context.Servicos.Add(servico2);

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return _context.Clientes.ToList();
}
```

Fiz o teste em MySQL e SQlite.

A inclusão funciona perfeitamente, criando as tabelas e as relações, mas a pesquisa está valorizando o objeto ClientesServicos da última entidade Cliente, que por sua vez também tem um objeto Cliente dentro dele, que também tem uma entidade ClientesServicos, assim sucessivamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está de errado com o código ou como fazer com que apenas o primeiro nível da entidade join seja valorizado na pesquisa?

Comment: São dois objetos diferentes, o objeto com `ClienteId` **1** tem uma lista de `ClientesServiço`?

Comment: @Barbetta sim, os dois objetos foram valorizados igualmente, na teoria, se o último volta ClienteServico valorizado, o primeiro deveria voltar também

Answer (score 0):

Bem, de acordo com [esse post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231756/entity-framework-core-returns-all-nested-children-when-using-include-on-a-man), isso parece ser um padrão do EF Core 2 e o correto é utilizar DTO + Projection. Utilizando o tutorial [nesse link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5), desenvolvi o seguinte:

Classe DTO com uma lista de nome dos serviços:

```
public class ClienteDto
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string NomeEmpresa { get; set; }
    public string NomeContato { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ConteudoConversa { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataHoraConversa { get; set; }
    public List<string> NomeServico { get; set; }
}
```

Alteração no Controller:

```
return _context.Clientes.Select(x => new ClienteDto()
        {
            ClienteId = x.ClienteId, 
            NomeEmpresa = x.NomeEmpresa, 
            NomeContato = x.NomeContato, 
            Telefone = x.Telefone, 
            Email = x.Email, 
            ConteudoConversa = x.ConteudoConversa, 
            DataHoraConversa = x.DataHoraConversa,
            NomeServico = x.ClienteServico.Select(c => c.Servico.NomeServico).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```